# How to set WiFi network priority?

Tags: wifi

I understand that I can set up multiple WiFis by adding to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` (as prescribed in [Setting WiFi Up Via The Command Line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md)).

Let's say I have two WiFis registered: `wifi_A` and `wifi_B`

When I unplug router `wifi_A`, and reboot my raspberry to command line, it automatically connects to `wifi_B`. When I unplug router `wifi_B`, and reboot my raspberry to command line, it automatically connects to `wifi_A`. So far so good.

But, let's say both routers are available, how can I set priorities? E.g. I'd like my Raspberry to connect to `wifi_B` upon reboot?

My second question is: Let's say I am in the command line mode and I am currently connected to `wifi_B`. How can I connect to `wifi_A` instead?

Comment: Unless you list your config files, all you will get is a lot of speculation (at best).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> But, let's say both routers are available, how can I set priorities?

You can set priorities for network as follows:

```
network={
    ssid="wifi_A"
    psk="passwordOfA"
    priority=1
}
network={
   ssid="wifi_B"
   psk="passwordOfB"
   priority=2
}
```

By default priority of all networks is 0, set higher priority to prioritize as per your need.

> Let's say I am in the command line mode and I am currently connected
> to wifi_B. How can I connect to wifi_A instead?

For that use the commands:

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 list_networks
```

to get a list of your configured networks. And to connect to first network:

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 select_network 0
```

To shift from `wifi_A` to `wifi_B` use:

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 select_network 1
```

**Note:** Using select_network disables until next boot all other Wifis. So if this Wifi goes away your device will remain offline until you enable or select another network, see https://nxmnpg.lemoda.net/8/wpa_cli
You can use `wpa_cli -i wlan0 enable_network all` to re-enable them after switching to the other network to avoid beeing stuck on one wifi.

Comment: to check which number to use in `wpa_cli select_network #`, run `wpa_cli list_networks` first.

Comment: This does not work for me with a Pi 3+ on Stretch. Ran wpa_cli list_networks and got the network numbers, and then wpa_cli select_network 2. System responded with OK but iwconfig shows it's still connected to the original network.

Comment: A note for clarity: The `priority` value is applied as a higher value meaning higher priority. i.e. networks are _not_ selected in numeric/counting order (zero first).

Comment: On Buster, there is an interface "p2p-dev-wlan0", which I found is selected by default. Therefore, the commands above need to include `-i wlan0`. For example: `wpa_cli -i wlan0 select_network 0`. This works and it's perfect for my application because it doesn't need `sudo`

Comment: Thank you very much for giving a description for priority, which is a very essential thing.

Comment: Also to check the PI is actually on the selected network use: `iw wlan0 info`

Answer (score 18):

> E.g. I'd like my raspberry to connect to `wifi_B` upon reboot?

Add `priority=2` to the `wifi_B` block and `priority=1` to the `wifi_A` block in the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file.

> Let's say I am in command line mode and I am currently connected to `wifi_B`. How can I connect to `wifi_A` instead?

You can create a separate config file for each of the SSIDs and specify it explicitly:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -iwlan0 -c</path/to/config_for_wifi_A>
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

Comment: Using your approach, I can switch from one WiFi network to the other only once, can't switch back (or to another WiFi_C for ex.). After using the `wpa_supplicant` command to do the 1st switch, using it again I get a message `ctrl-iface exists and seems to be in use - cannot override it` \n `Delete '/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0' manually if it is not used anymore` etc ... And after `sudo dhclient wlan0` I'm being told `RTMETLINK answers: File exists`. Is this what to expect?

Comment: you need to first shutdown the connection with `wpa_cli terminate` and then connect to another with `wpa_supplicant`, there's also a more complicated way without shutting it down [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#Connecting_with_wpa_cli)

Comment: It's worth noting explicitly that higher-numbered priorities get used first.  (So, the colloquial idea of "1st priority" is *not* what `priority=1` means, in the presence of a `priority=2` (or `priority=800`, or whatever).  Your answer implies this, given a careful read of both question and answer, just... worth pointing out, since it's potentially counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 12):

So to elaborate on the full solution here:

```
network={
    ssid="wifi_A"
    psk="passwordOfA"
    priority=1 #lower priority
}
network={
   ssid="wifi_B"
   psk="passwordOfB"
   priority=2 #higher priority
}
```

Then after initial reboot, to actively switch networks (without a secondary reboot):

```
sudo wpa_cli list_networks #show them!
sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 select_network 0 #0, 1, etc.  Note: Networks are NOT the same number as your priority in the wpa_supplicant
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments in the example! It's very counter-intuitive that higher priority is further in the sequence of natural numbers... I've spent quite some time trying to figure out why "first" priority was ignored in favor of "second" priority.