# how to select a particular WiFi SSID from the command line?

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch, jessie-lite

On a freshly imaged stretch lite (it would be the same on a regular stretch or jessie) I've set-up `wpa_supplicant.conf` with 2 known wifi networks. After boot, the system selects one of the network specified in `wpa_supplicant.conf`,   but how do I select the other one from the command line (without editing `wpa_supplicant.conf` of course!)?

Comment: Why? What are you attempting to achieve?

Comment: Just chose one network over the other one. One of the SSID is my phone hotspot the other is a company's and requires a different password every 24hrs.

Comment: Related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/58304/63024

Comment: See this for more thorough explanations:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58304/how-to-set-wifi-network-priority

Answer (score 2):

It is not AFAIK possible to select by SSID, but you can manually select with something like the following.

```
wpa_cli select_network 1
```

It is quite a while since I used this, but networks are identified by position in `wpa_supplicant.conf`.

If you want to prefer one network setting priority is a better method.

Comment: So the index 1 in `wpa_cli select_network 1` corresponds to the order of my networks in wpa_supplicant.conf? I'll try this soon.

Comment: Feedbacks on your answer: (1) `wpa_cli select_network x` with x = 0 or 1 returns the same `Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0'` `OK`, and with both WiFi networks correctly broadcasting, my RPi still connects to only one of them, so this doesn't allow to switch between networks. (2) The position in `wpa_supplicant.conf` does not select the priority (setting my own hotspot in 2nd position in `wpa_supplicant.conf` will chose it even with the other WiFi turned on and set in 1st position).

Comment: And (3): I suppose that by *setting priority* you mean adding `priority = x` with x = 1, 2, ... inside `network {...}` in `wpa_supplicant.conf`?

Comment: As I said it has been some time since I used it (while testing with a number of AP). According to  `wpa_cli list_networks` it works, I just switched from `1 PiNET any [CURRENT]` to `1 PiNET any [DISABLED]` but `iwconfig` shows `wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"PiNET"` Maybe the wireless hook in `dhcpcd` gets in the way.

Comment: Here's my experiment: (a) after reboot I'm connected to wifi_hotspot. (b) `wpa_cli list_networks` shows the 2 lines `0 other_wifi any` and `1 myhostpot any` (c) `wpa_cli select_network 1` (d) `wpa_cli list_networks` then shows `0 other_wifi any [DISABLED]` and `1 myhostpot any [CURRENT]` (e) `wpa_cli select_network 0` (f) `wpa_cli list_networks` shows `0 other_wifi any [CURRENT]` `1 myhostpot any [DISABLED]`. But I still see me as a connected user on my hotspot and still have the same IP address (ifconfig), and can do apt-get install (I didn't set the other wifi password so not connectd)!