# different static ip for different wifi network

Tags: static-ip

I am just new to the pi and I like to play with it when I am home. Now I would also like it if I would be able to play with it when I am on the go. I figured out that it is possible to connect the pi to my phone network and then I am able to use termius to work with the pi. Now i would like to know if it is possible to give the pi a static ip address for when it is connected to my home wifi and a different static ip address for when it connects to my phone network when i am on the go? so for example i would like to give static ip adress 192.168.179.95 tot my pi when it connects to my home wifi but ip adress 192.168.44.95 when it connects to my phone wifi.

Comment: You may want to view https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58304/how-to-set-wifi-network-priority   (which is mostly about how to configure it to search for preferred WiFi networks (e.g. a home network vs. your phone network when the home network is not available) and set the priority.

Comment: Also see:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address

Comment: **Does the pi search for familiar networks and connect to them automaticly?** No, not out of the box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address)